# using 3.10 gnuradio and hackrf to make a signal generator

Tags: gnuradio, hackrf

I have had a gnu radio program using 3.7 and it worked with hackrf.  Now 3.10 offers soapy interface and osmosdr. I don't know how to interface either one with hackrf.

Answer (score 3):

As I explained multiple times before, pick a suitable sampling rate, connect your signal source to your Soapy HackRF Sink. Done.

[image: Minimal HackRF flowgraph]

(I enabled the display of what I entered in the fields for you. Your blocks would by default just show what's after the "=", but you enter what is before.)

You can download the full flowgraph, which has nice sliders for everything from tone amplitude to tone frequency, RF gain and carrier frequency, [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/marcusmueller/360aa8d07baec0b25063f75e27cde02f/raw/8f97745e27fc007f161e2bede9144106cf664b7b/hackrf.grc) as well as a Display; the whole thing isn't big, it looks like this:

[image: Full Flowgraph]

In action, you'll see this:

[image: In action]

I'm sadly not here to assist you to recreate it – all the mechanics of finding blocks, connecting them, using sliders and so on is covered in the [official GNU Radio Tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org).

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: I am getting this error" Executing: C:\Users\markl\anaconda3\envs\gnuradio\python.exe -u C:\Users\markl\Downloads\simple_hackrf.py Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\markl\Downloads\simple_hackrf.py", line 225, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\markl\Downloads\simple_hackrf.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.soapy_hackrf_sink_0 = soapy.sink(dev, "fc32", 1, '',
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: no hackrf device matches

>>> Done (return code 1)" even though i did install zadig usb driver

Comment: I think its my lovely newmachine that has usb3 and doesnt really slow down to recognize slower usb2 boards like hackrf which I think should work on older machine that has true usb2 board that could be recognized by windows and python as such

Comment: You're just jumping to conclusions. You said you were able to install the Zadig driver, which means you were able to select the HackRF from a list of detected devices.

Comment: hackrf was not one of the choices only the local devices. not the usb

Comment: Why did you then claim you've installed the zadig driver? That's not the case.

Comment: because when I run >SoapySDRUtil --info I get   Available factories... hackrf
Available converters...
 -  CF32 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]
 -  CS16 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]
 -  CS32 -> [CS32]
 -   CS8 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8, CU16, CU8]
 -  CU16 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8]
 -   CU8 -> [CF32, CS16, CS8]
 -   F32 -> [F32, S16, S8, U16, U8]
 -   S16 -> [F32, S16, S8, U16, U8]
 -   S32 -> [S32]
 -    S8 -> [F32, S16, S8, U16, U8]
 -   U16 -> [F32, S16, S8]
 -    U8 -> [F32, S16, S8]

Comment: [link]https://imgur.com/a/iTpkbuZ) _italic_ **bold**  _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Try to be coherent! Also, you're **once again** showing a different flow graph than the one I built for you. I will stop reacting to you now, you've been an exhausting sink of time.

Comment: all I was showing you was that windows 11 is ignoring hackrf  from being taged so that the zadig can do its magic. that was the chain of thought it has very little to do with your diagram if the device is not being loaded then it becomes ineffective. if anyone knows how to get hackrf to become taged by the process instead of being shunned from the get go

Comment: you see, none of this has to do with GNU Radio 3.7 vs 3.10, you're bringing up new things every other comment, you jump back to old things but don't explain, you give incorrect information on what you've done and sprinkle in speculation that you then contradict yourself. As someone who's not in your brain, I really tried, but can't help you with that.

Comment: there is a chain of events to unravel why hackrf is being ignored and zadig doesnt load it with the proper driver and then gnuradio produce the proper diagram. the weakest link in all of this win 11 ignoring the hackrf for some unknown reason

Answer (score -2):

yes! I have figured my problem,I simply checked the cable, it wasn't a data cable, but just a 5v one. But I have another question in gnuradio3.7 there was a "if gain" - in hackrf portion. how do I get that now, before if I turned it on I used to get almost 10 dbm output just from hackrf with out an amp.to add my own amp/ I can probably get to 30 dbm.

[image: if 14db just turns it on 0db turns it off] in gnuradio3.7

Comment: I did try other hackrf source and sink very b buggy signal dbm is -40dbm after amp it doesnt even reach of scope must be below -10dbm. I really would like some assistance not pointing at hackrf

Comment: Comments are generally not for asking  new questions.