# Unstable frequency generator using gnuradio 3.10

Tags: gnuradio, signal-identification, hackrf

I run gnuradio on Windows 11 using anaconda install. It uses hackrf without portapack. I am using a signal amp from an F16 fighter jet. It requires 10 dBm input and runs on 24 V 2 A. [Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYMy.jpg)

It can tolerate the 12.5 dBm I am using – Marcus Müller’s suggested [signal generator for ver 3.10](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/21537/using-3-10-gnuradio-and-hackrf-to-make-a-signal-generator).

I can’t get a stable frequency or peak-to-peak reading. My Hantek oscilloscope is all over the place from [1 V to 100 V](https://youtube.com/shorts/A8LwgCNl9CA?).

Is there a problem with the gnuradio program that caused the instability? Maybe the "soapy hackrf" is not usable or maybe there is a better solution. Maybe hackrf is putting signal faster than 2 ns that causes Hantek to become so unstable. [This Hantek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHcwj.jpg) can produce a very stable frequency in adj mode. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSlSGCbadUk) of my hackrf with portapack.

Can anyone explain how to turn the hackrf into a very stable frequency generator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stable frequency and peak to peak voltage are not present](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/stable-frequency-and-peak-to-peak-voltage-are-not-present)

Comment: You can't just ask the same question again after the last one got closed. Especially not if it got closed for lack of clarity.

Comment: I didnt get an answer so far I got that my question is closed

Comment: no, your question is plain nonsensical. You're measuring 100V out of a device with a 5V supply, and expecting 44 dBm (that's 14 dBW, i.e., > 20 W) out of a device with maybe 20 dBm output. So, one of two things are true: you are either forgetting to mention a big amplifier, quite likely to blame for fluctuations, or your measurement setup is somehow fundamentally broken and misinterpreted by you. We can't guess that; you are simply not doing enough to 1. structure your question 2. describing your overall system, 3. demonstrating error isolation efforts.

Comment: that all **aside**, it's very strictly against the rules to simply re-post the same question again. What do you expect us to do? Be joyous that you don't care for our rules? Fix the original question. Don't just repeat.

Comment: So, did you edit your identical previous question to include full system information, including why you're expecting such high amplitudes, including a full rundown of your setup, including the amplifier that I suspect you have? It's not that hard to guess that to will have to describe your whole system if you measure instability at the output. The one thing that is relatively unlikely is that *software* is to blame here.

Comment: Hi, at least one of the links you added is incorrect. Please also don't add information in the comments here that you don't add to the question. Finally, we *really* need you to *structure* this question, I still am having a very hard time understanding it. I'd propose this: You make three sections (with empty lines in between):

Comment: The first would be "**Experimental setup**", where you tell us about the software and the hardware, including actual type information on the amplifier ("something from ebay" doesn't help; please also include information on power supplies and so), your photo, and the relevant settings on your oscilloscope.

Comment: The second would be "**Problem description**" where you explain what you are exactly expecting to see (and really, try to be very exact here), and how what you see differs. Also explain what you've tried to narrow down the source – for example, whether you tried the same setup without the amplifier, or with the amplifier but a different power supply, and so. In essence, I think you've probably worked a lot on that problem – but you're really not letting us now, so we can't know what you've already excluded as possible problem, and what is just an "idea" of yours.

Comment: And the third, and final, paragraph would be "**Question**", where you ask a single, clear question. Something arising from the things you could not exclude as problem in the second section. A question sentence which could have a correct answer! Then, we could actually start working on answers.

Comment: The goal here is to make a question that the experts here would look at and say "oh, yes, that might by this and that reason", without having to go through pages of comments and making a lot of guesses. I know that is a lot of work, and it's easier for some than for others, but right now, the expert here says "I really have no idea how the setup works and what possible sources of problems are, it just strikes me that the approach markl17 has so far won't lead us anywhere".

Comment: Mr. muller I think I pollished it but no one is volunteering any comments besides the snide once "you didnt do it our way"

Comment: sorry, who made any snide remarks? you just fixed this, and I have sleep to have and work to do, so my apologies for not reacting to your changes right away. Anyways, now your literal question is, still: "is there a problem with the gnuradio program that caused the instability", and the answer is **no**. Software is not the instable part here. It's still probably improper wiring or insufficient power supply. You could also easily verify that – attach your scope to the hackrf, not to your amplifier. The amplitude should be nice and steady. If it's not,check your coax cabling,connectors at scope

Comment: I did that before i started writing and searching for help. without any amplification the signal is still unstable. thats why I thought that maybe if hackrf is sending a signal much faster than 2ns and hackrf breaks up the analog sinewave it would probably come to these results catching pieces of the sine wave

Comment: again, we can only read what you write into your question. Everything that you do not write we have to assume you did not do. Please be more verbose. It's really not helpful for you getting help if you're omitting crucial information in your question! So, if you can already see the unstability we need to fix, then adding the amplifier makes the whole system just more complex and makes debugging it harder. Honestly, you just wasted a lot of my time (and yours!) by not saying that, and by showing traces that show the amplified output. Sigh. I'll be honest: I don't *want* to spend more time on

Comment: this problem – every interaction with you boils down to "why didn't you say that earlier, instead of starting with the crudest theory, and a confusing host of additional complications". I'm very sorry that I made you spend time improving your question – it's just that this eats through my spare time energy, and I'll have to make a cut here. My apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142769/discussion-between-markl17-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: I'm really sorry, I won't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using 3.10 gnuradio and hackrf to make a signal generator](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/21537/using-3-10-gnuradio-and-hackrf-to-make-a-signal-generator)

Answer (score 1):

The videos and photos provided are of substantially different configurations so this isn't just one puzzle, it is many. In the [last video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSlSGCbadUk), it appears the HackRF is being instructed to tune to 120 MHz with a 4 MHz bandwidth. That means it will be able to produce signal from 118 MHz to 122 MHz. The frequency plot shows that the CW being generated is at 151.2 MHz. This is way outside of the 4 MHz configured bandwidth. Poor signal production should be expected when asking the radio to do the impossible.